# Export java ca certificate so that it is usable from go

Tags: java, go, ssl

I need to integrate java service with go app, which can be configured to specify the CA certificate file to use when checking TLS. I'm not familiar with go. The Java rest endpoint is secured with self-signed certificate.

I'm trying to export it using `keytool` like this:

```
keytool -export -alias rootca -file ca.crt -keystore cacerts
```

The `ca.crt` file is checkable with keytool itself with command:

```
keytool -printcert -v -file ca.crt
```

Now when I try to use this file in go app, which is [prometheus](https://prometheus.io) by passing `tls_config` with `ca_cert` value pointing to exported file I get an error:

> err="error creating HTTP client: unable to use specified CA cert /etc/prometheus/ssl/ca.crt"

The Prometheus is using the the go's standart `crypto/tls` so my questions is:

- Is the way I exported Java file is correct and usable?
- How can I translate exported Java CA file to the format that Go will understand and use?

Comment: The certificate is probably in binary format. If it does not contain a readable header (just open it with a text editor), you need to convert it to PEM: `openssl x509 -in cert.cer -out cert.pem`

Comment: @Marc yes, it's in binary, however the suggested command doesn't work. It fails with `4654165440:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`

Comment: You can tell openssl the actual input format: `openssl x509 -in cert.cer -out cert.pem -inform DER`, and even optionally output form with `-outform PEM`. You can also try the `-rfc` option to `keytool -printcert` to output in PEM format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the man page for `keytool`, under the `-exportcert` command:

> The certificate is by default output in binary encoding.

The encoding in question is [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690) which is a binary representation of the certificate data.

However, the Go standard library expects [PEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail) encoding which is just base64 of the DER data plus some header/footer.

You have (at least) two options:

### Tell `keytool` to export in PEM format

This is done using the `-rfc` flag to the `-exportcerts` command. Per the man page:

> If the -rfc option is specified, then the output in the printable
> encoding format defined by the Internet RFC 1421 Certificate Encoding
> Standard.

[RFC1421](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1421) is the one for PEM.

### Convert from DER to PEM

This can be done using openssl using the following:

```
openssl -in exported_file.der -inform DER -out ca.crt
```